# C++ noexcept specification depending on data members

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

this declaration is ok:

```
void memberFunction(T& functor, double value)noexcept(noexcept(functor(value)));
```

for a

```
template<class T> 
class MyClass{
    public: 
        void memberFunction(T& functor, double value)noexcept(noexcept(functor(value))); 
};
```

Let's say that MyClass has a functor data member:

```
template<class T> 
class MyClass{
    public: 
        //ctor 
        ... 
        void memberFunction(double value); 
    private: 
        T functor; 
};
```

I want to write the noexcept specification as I did in the previous case, 
I tried this:

```
void memberFunction(double value)noexcept(noexcept(functor(value)));
```

but the compiler tells me that functor is not the scope. 
The following doesn't work for analogous reasons:

```
void memberFunction(double value)noexcept(noexcept(this->functor(value)));
```

And the following can't work because I have some classes used as T which lacks 
a default constructor:

```
void memberFunction(double value)noexcept(noexcept(T()(value)));
```

The following is syntatically wrong:

```
void memberFunction(double value)noexcept(noexcept(T::operator(double)));
```

eve though it pictorically explains well what I want.

Any suggestion? 
For the moment I gave up with the specification...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::declval<T>()` simulates an rvalue `T` instance.  `std::declval<T&>()` simulates an lvalue `T` instance.  Use this in place of `T()`.

Answer (score 2):

That `noexcept` specification is part of the declaration for `memberFunction` and therefore doesn't have access to any member data declared afterwards.

The simple fix is to move the declaration of `functor` above `memberFunction`:

```
template<class T> 
class MyClass{
    private: 
        T functor; 
    public: 
        //ctor 
        ... 
        void memberFunction(double value); 
};
```